# How do i get my NVIDIA GF108 driver installed on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

Hi I have the latest Kali Linux on my machine. I want my gpu to do pool mining while my machine is idle because I don't use it for anything like gaming or the like. I have followed as many driver tuts as I could find but most of them are just reposts of the one on the kali website. https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/

I am lost I did everything even at one stage purged the debian packages in VT and tried installing the legacy driver to which I got errors during installation and had to refer to the above guide to get me working again. I even tried the suggestions in another post on this site, to no avail.

I have got it as far as to show me that the kernel modules are Nvidia but I can't get Nvidia as the Driver.

I have also succeeded in stopping my second monitor from working.

I am about ready to revert back to the nouveau but that will defeat the purpose of getting my device to be valuable even if only slightly.

I have the following output

```
└─$ lspci -s 01:00.0 -v                                    
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 3000 [disabled] [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at f1080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: nvidia


$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Comment: First, please use another distro, Kali is not meant to used as a general desktop. Any software which runs on it is readily available elsewhere. Secondly, try running those commands as root.

Comment: Ok thanks if that is the only option then I'll just revert I have two distros on my machine. I use the kali for pentesting mainly I just thought I would use some of the machine's downtime. Thank you for your input.